# Points on collision (points only working for first platform)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to make doodle jump on Unity with a difference that when I land on a platform, 10 points are added. However this is only working for the first platform. I start from 0 and when i go on first platform i get 10 points, but it stops there.

What is wrong with my code please why won't this keep happening for the other platforms?

```
public class PlatformScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int currentScore;
    public Text displayScore;

    public float jumpForce = 10f; 

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.y <= 0) {

            Rigidbody2D rb = collision.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

            if (rb != null) {
                Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;
                velocity.y = jumpForce; 
                rb.velocity = velocity;
            }

            Destroy (gameObject);
            currentScore += 10;                
            Update ();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        displayScore.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
    }
}
```

Also, this is my level generation page. The platforms generate at random:

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject platformPrefab;

public int numberOfPlatforms = 200;
public float levelWidth = 3f;
public float minY = 1f; 
public float maxY = 3.2f;


void Start () {
    Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 ();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatforms; i++) 
    {
        spawnPosition.y += Random.Range (minY, maxY);
        spawnPosition.x = Random.Range (-levelWidth, levelWidth); 
        Instantiate (platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity); 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm super new  to Unity as you may have noticed.

Comment: Don't call the `Update` function manually. This function is automatically called by Unity.

Comment: Now it completely doesn't work .. the points just remain at 0

Comment: You've declared `currentScore` in the current script, I'm pretty sure that the script is an instance per game object that it's attached to, so you basically have a lot of instances of `currentScore` that are all zero. When you hit the platform you add 10 and then destroy the platform. This means you only ever get a value of 10 for score. I don't know unity though so this may not be accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're destroying the platform that holds the score. Save the data in a globally accessible (shared between platforms) object such as your `LevelGenerator`. With a little shuffling, it would look something like this (`static` used for simplicty);

```
public class PlatformScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce = 10f;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.relativeVelocity.y <= 0)
        {
            Rigidbody2D rb = collision.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            if (rb != null)
            {
                Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;
                velocity.y = jumpForce;
                rb.velocity = velocity;
            }

            // update our global score
            LevelGenerator.currentScore += 10;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // global persistent data
    public static int currentScore;

    public Text displayScore;
    public GameObject platformPrefab;

    public int numberOfPlatforms = 200;
    public float levelWidth = 3f;
    public float minY = 1f;
    public float maxY = 3.2f;

    void Start ()
    {
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlatforms; i++)
        {
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(minY, maxY);
            spawnPosition.x = Random.Range(-levelWidth, levelWidth);
            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        displayScore.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg no it worked now!!!!! (I forgot to save LOL) !
Thanks Lece!!!!!!! <3

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou :D Now I just need to reset it back to 0 for when he dies :D Don't think that should be TOO hard though :D

Comment: Awesome and you're welcome! Just do `LevelGenerator.currentScore = 0;` when he dies.

Comment: You can accept Lece's answer if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

> However this is only working for the first platform. I start from 0
>   and when i go on first platform i get 10 points, but it stops there.

That's because you are destroying it(the GameObject your `PlatformScript` script is attached to) with `Destroy (gameObject);`.

If the `PlatformScript` script is attached to the Platform and your goal is to destroy that other GameObject then use `Destroy(collision.gameObject);` instead of `Destroy (gameObject);`.

Finally, do not call the `Update` function manually. This function is automatically called by Unity. Also, it is better to update the `displayScore` text when the `currentScore` is modified instead of every frame in the `Update` function.

---

If that doesn't work, use `Debug.Log` to verify that `OnCollisionEnter2D` is being called. Also use it to verify that  `if (collision.relativeVelocity.y <= 0)` is even evaluating to `true`. If any of these two is `false` then your score won't update. See the fixed `OnCollisionEnter2D` function below. Use that to debug your code.

Your new code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision detected!");

    if (collision.relativeVelocity.y <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("RelativeVelocity <=0");
        Rigidbody2D rb = collision.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;
            velocity.y = jumpForce;
            rb.velocity = velocity;
        }
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);

        currentScore += 10;
        displayScore.text = "Score: " + currentScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried everything you just said and none of it worked.

Comment: With Destroy(collision.gameObject), it wouldn't even let the player jump as the level sorts of reloads on itself each time and this happens repeatedly.

I also tried removing the Destroy(gameObject) and the points didn't work either. They just went up from 0 to 10 and remained the same. Basically the same problem as before.

I don't think the destroy is the problem